# How to display buttons in Evince?

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, xfce, evince, greybird

I like Evince so far, I can read stuff just fine.

However, instead of buttons for navigating, I see buttons with words for `Previous` or `Next` (technically, they aren't *buttons* as they have no borders at all, they are just plain text) and `Open Folder`as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

Is it possible to get those buttons?

My system information:

- Xubuntu 12.10
- Xfce with Greybird theme and the default icon set.

Comment: Can you get a screenshot?.

Comment: @UriHerrera Sure here you go: http://imgur.com/occvUvV :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up the XFCE Configuration Settings, then go to Appearance, then go to the Configuration tab, after that select Icons from the **Toolbar Style** drop down menu.

Comment: Oh... I have overlooked that option entirely. Thank you!